# Dynamically sharing file/folder between users on the same machine with subdirectory

Tags: file-permissions, access-control-list, file-sharing, user-permissions

I have 3000+ local users on my Linux system. I want to set permissions dynamically for folder or files.
I came across ACLs (Access Control Lists) when I researched this topic. All users home location must be hidden from other user.
But what if I want to give permissions for certain files or folders in subfolders of the user home page then what should I do?

Actually, what I want to tell is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGucd.png)

When I blocking /user2 directory for /user1 then I can't access user2's subdirectory from user1. How can I solve this?

I looked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/728915/how-to-share-files-folders-between-users-on-same-linux-machine) although it is not completely similar to my problem. I don't want users to see each other's directories.

Where is my life saver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, file ACLs can do this. What you want is to give the traverse (`x`) permission, but not the read (`r`) permission. For directories:

- Traverse allows a user to traverse the directory node along the directory tree. In command terms it lets them run `cd directory`.
- Read allows the user to read the directory's contents. In command terms it lets them run `ls directory`.

So for user1 in your diagram:

```
# Allow user1 to cd /home/user2/folder/subfolder/subfolder:
setfacl -R -m u:user1:x /home/user2/folder/subfolder/subfolder
# Allow user1 to ls /home/user2/folder/subfolder/subfolder:
setfacl    -m u:user1:r /home/user2/folder/subfolder/subfolder
```

Note that:

- In the first command you want the `-R` (recursive) flag, because you need to set the `x` permission on all of the parent directories. Without that, user1 won't be able to get to the leaf directory to read it, even if you give them read permission there.
- In the second command you *don't* want `-R`, because you only want to grant read permission to the leaf directory - not to any of its parents.

See [Understanding Linux directory permissions reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790686/understanding-linux-directory-permissions-reasoning).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was a nice explanation